# Antd React - How can i check all tree nodes with a select all checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to be able to check all tree node when i check the Check all checkbox, this is an example below :
[image]

[This is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e4qri7?file=index.js), have you any idea which state should I change please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can handle all cases like this with custom checkbox.

```
  let getAllKeys = (tree) => {
    let result = [];
    tree.forEach((x) => {
      let childKeys = [];
      if (x.children) {
        childKeys = getAllKeys(x.children);
      }

      result.push(...[x.key, ...childKeys]);
    });

    return result;
  };

  const allKeys = getAllKeys(treeData);

  const onChange = () => {
    if (checkedKeys.length === allKeys.length) {
      setCheckedKeys([]);
    } else {
      setCheckedKeys(allKeys);
    }
  };
```

JSX

```
     <Checkbox
        onChange={onChange}
        checked={checkedKeys.length === allKeys.length ? true : false}
      >
        Select All
      </Checkbox>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e4qri7-myat8v)

Comment: Hi, what if i want to use Checkbox separatly without editing my TreeData ?

Comment: You can do it like @Giorgi Moniava, but his code does not meet all conditions. You must consider if any of the children is not selected you must programlly deselect `Select all`  checkbox and also  select `Select all` checkbox when all childrens was selected. Conclusion, you have more problems and more useless code. Just use correct `TreeData`.

Comment: Hi @Vitaliy Rayets, so how can i handle all this case please ?

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Mine covered basic case to select all, but yeah if OP needs all those features, he/she will need more code.

Comment: I'm new to react and antd, i've readed the antd documentation but i did not found any solution to my problem.. Can anyone halpe me please to perform this action ? thank you

Comment: @Tania12, I edited answer and demo, with all cases.